# Visual Studio 2015 não mostra conteúdo de QString durante debug/depuração

Tags: c++, qt, debug

Estou utilizando o Visual Studio 2015 para desenvolver uma aplicação em Qt 5. Tudo funciona corretamente, mas quando tento depurar o código e inspecionar uma variável do tipo `QString`, o debug não mostra o conteúdo (texto) da variável, mas sim informações internas da alocação do objeto (tanto no *tooltip* quando eu passo o mouse sobre a variável, como na janela de *Watch*):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Há alguma forma de fazer o VS exibir o conteúdo textual da variável, tal como ele faz com strings ANSI e STL?

Comment: Programo em Lazarus, e nele temos um debug não muito eficiente, mas quando uma variável mostra um endereço, como no seu caso, usamos o operados ^ para mostrar o conteúdo do endereço. No seu caso, parece que o VS tem formas de tratar isso: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22324166/visual-studio-2012-and-qt4-8-5-how-to-see-qstring-contents-in-debug-mode

Comment: Sim, verdade. De fato eu estava respondendo à minha própria pergunta. Só demorei porque o sistema não deixou eu postar o conteúdo que eu havia originalmente preparado (tava reclamando que era muito grande... droga... rs). Mas mesmo assim, obrigado pela ajuda. :)

Comment: Que khda heim? Eu gastei um tempão respondendo, e é duplicada (eu mesmo já havia colocado esse conteúdo aqui. rs). Sorry galera. Optei por não remover porque aqui há informação sobre a atualização para a versão 5.7 do Qt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O Visual Studio tem um recurso chamado [Visualização Customizada de Objetos Nativos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj620914.aspx) (uma tradução livre do original em inglês *Custom Views of Native Objects*). No blog da Microsoft tem [um exemplo bem bacana](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/09/28/debug-visualizers-in-visual-c-2015/).

> O arquivo natvis deve ser adicionado ao projeto, para uso particular,
>   ou à pasta `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers` para uso geral.

Até algum tempo existia o [Qt Visual Studio Add-in](http://doc.qt.io/vs-addin/), que ao ser instalado fornecia uma série de facilidades para a utilização do Qt no VS, **incluindo um arquivo natvis**. Esse add-in está agora obsoleta (*deprecated*) mas você pode utilizar seu arquivo `qt5.natvis` (encontrado em alguns repositórios na Internet, tal como [esse](https://github.com/a1ext/labeless/blob/master/test/qt5.natvis)). Parte do arquivo é reproduzido abaixo, mas baixe-o da fonte original (ele é muito grande para caber todo aqui):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AutoVisualizer xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/debugger/natvis/2010">
    <Type Name="QPoint">
        <AlternativeType Name="QPointF"/>
        <DisplayString>{{ x = {xp}, y = {yp} }}</DisplayString>
        <Expand>
            <Item Name="[x]">xp</Item>
            <Item Name="[y]">yp</Item>
        </Expand>
    </Type>
    <Type Name="QRect">
        <DisplayString>{{ x = {x1}, y = {y1}, width = {x2 - x1 + 1}, height = {y2 - y1 + 1} }}</DisplayString>
        <Expand>
            <Item Name="[x]">x1</Item>
            <Item Name="[y]">y1</Item>
            <Item Name="[width]">x2 - x1 + 1</Item>
            <Item Name="[height]">y2 - y1 + 1</Item>
        </Expand>
    </Type>
    <Type Name="QRectF">
        <DisplayString>{{ x = {xp}, y = {yp}, width = {w}, height = {h} }}</DisplayString>
        <Expand>
            <Item Name="[x]">xp</Item>
            <Item Name="[y]">yp</Item>
            <Item Name="[width]">w</Item>
            <Item Name="[height]">h</Item>
        </Expand>
    </Type>
    <Type Name="QSize">
        <AlternativeType Name="QSizeF"/>
        <DisplayString>{{ width = {wd}, height = {ht} }}</DisplayString>
        <Expand>
            <Item Name="[width]">wd</Item>
            <Item Name="[height]">ht</Item>
        </Expand>
    </Type>
    <Type Name="QLine">
        <AlternativeType Name="QLineF"/>
        <DisplayString>{{ start point = {pt1}, end point = {pt2} }}</DisplayString>
        <Expand>
            <Synthetic Name="[start point]">
                <DisplayString>{pt1}</DisplayString>
                <Expand>
                    <ExpandedItem>pt1</ExpandedItem>
                </Expand>
            </Synthetic>
            <Synthetic Name="[end point]">
                <DisplayString>{pt2}</DisplayString>
                <Expand>
                    <ExpandedItem>pt2</ExpandedItem>
                </Expand>
            </Synthetic>
        </Expand>
    </Type>

    . . .

    <Type Name="QChar">
        <DisplayString>{ucs,c}</DisplayString>
        <StringView>ucs,c</StringView>
        <Expand>
            <Item Name="[latin 1]">ucs > 0xff ? '\0' : char(ucs),c</Item>
            <Item Name="[unicode]">ucs,c</Item>
        </Expand>
    </Type>
    <Type Name="QString">
        <DisplayString>{d-&gt;data,sub}</DisplayString>
        <StringView>d-&gt;data,sub</StringView>
        <Expand>
            <Item Name="[size]">d-&gt;size</Item>
            <Item Name="[referenced]">d-&gt;ref._q_value</Item>
            <ArrayItems>
                <Size>d-&gt;size</Size>
                <ValuePointer>(d->data),c</ValuePointer>
            </ArrayItems>
        </Expand>
    </Type>
    <Type Name="QT::QString">
        <DisplayString>{d-&gt;data,sub}</DisplayString>
        <StringView>d-&gt;data,sub</StringView>
        <Expand>
            <Item Name="[size]">d-&gt;size</Item>
            <Item Name="[referenced]">d-&gt;ref._q_value</Item>
            <ArrayItems>
                <Size>d-&gt;size</Size>
                <ValuePointer>(d->data),c</ValuePointer>
            </ArrayItems>
        </Expand>
    </Type>

    . . .

</AutoVisualizer>
```

A visualização de `QString` desse arquivo não funciona na versão 5.7 do Qt, mas há uma atualização que pode ser substituída ([a fonte é do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38615593/2896619)):

```
<Type Name="QString">
    <DisplayString IncludeView="nq">{((reinterpret_cast&lt;unsigned short*&gt;(d)) + d->offset / 2),sub}</DisplayString>
    <DisplayString ExcludeView="nq">"{((reinterpret_cast&lt;unsigned short*&gt;(d)) + d->offset / 2),sub}"</DisplayString>
    <StringView>((reinterpret_cast&lt;unsigned short*&gt;(d)) + d->offset / 2),sub</StringView>
    <Expand HideRawView="true">
        <Item ExcludeView="simple" Name="[size]">d-&gt;size</Item>
        <Item ExcludeView="simple" Name="[referenced]">d-&gt;ref.atomic._q_value</Item>
        <ArrayItems ExcludeView="simple">
            <Size>d-&gt;size</Size>
            <ValuePointer>((reinterpret_cast&lt;unsigned short*&gt;(d)) + d->offset / 2),c</ValuePointer>
        </ArrayItems>
    </Expand>
</Type>
```

Após salvar o arquivo natvis no diretório de visualizadores e reiniciar o VS, tem-se uma visualização apropriada de `QString`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]